# ejs dynamic form have all the same data

Tags: javascript, forms, post, ejs

I'm learning ejs and I have some trouble to get some thinge working properly. I'm trying to fill out a form when user click modify, depending on which line it is, but the form is showing all the same data and I don't know why.

For exemple, if i click "Modify on the second line of the table, it's supposed to take what's on second row and fill the form with dats. But it's always filling it using the first row data, regardless of where I click. Here's the code :

```
<% if(data.length){ 
    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
<tr>
  <td><%=data[i].ID%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].NOM%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].EMPLACEMENT%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].UTILITE%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].MARQUE%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].MODELE%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].NUMEROSERIE%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].PROCESSEUR%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].MEMOIRE%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].OS%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].CATEGORIE%></td>
  <td><%=data[i].VALEUR%></td>
  <td>
      <div class="container">

          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Modifier</button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modifier serveur</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form name="form1m" action="/update" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Inputm">ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inputm5" placeholder="ID" name="<%=data[i].ID%>" value="<%=data[i].ID%>" readonly>
                      </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Inputm">Nom</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inputm" placeholder="Nom" name="<%=data[i].NOM%>" value="<%=data[i].NOM%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input2m">Emplacement</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input2m" placeholder="Emplacement" name="EMPLACEMENT" value="<%=data[i].EMPLACEMENT%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input3m">Utilité</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input3m" placeholder="Utilité" name="UTILITE" value="<%=data[i].UTILITE%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input4m">Marque</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input4m" placeholder="Marque" name="MARQUE" value="<%=data[i].MARQUE%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input5m">Modèle</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input5m" placeholder="Modèle" name="MODELE" value="<%=data[i].MODELE%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input6m">Numéro de série</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input6m" placeholder="Numéro de série" name="NUMEROSERIE" value="<%=data[i].NUMEROSERIE%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input7m">Processeur</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input7m" placeholder="Processeur" name="PROCESSEUR" value="<%=data[i].PROCESSEUR%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input8m">Mémoire</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input8m" placeholder="Mémoire" name="MEMOIRE" value="<%=data[i].MEMOIRE%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input9m">OS</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input9m" placeholder="OS" name="OS" value="<%=data[i].OS%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input10m">Catégorie</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input10m" placeholder="Catégorie" name="CATEGORIE" value="<%=data[i].CATEGORIE%>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input11m">Valeur</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input11m" placeholder="Valeur" name="VALEUR" value="<%=data[i].VALEUR%>">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="Soumettre" value="Soumettre" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Here's how data looks like:

[image: data]

Data are different, but when I click edit, it shows data only from the first row.

Heres the rendered HTML (for the two rows in my last screenshot) :

```
 <tr>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>S</td>
  <td>HP</td>
  <td>EWE</td>
  <td>DFERu</td>
  <td>weWE</td>
  <td>wesdf</td>
  <td>ESFDdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</td>
  <td>Cdeqawed</td>
  <td>989</td>
  <td>
      <div class="container">

          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Modifier</button>

          <!-- Modal -->

          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modifier serveur</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form name="form1m" action="/update" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Inputm">ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inputm5-7" placeholder="ID" name="ID" value="20" readonly>
                      </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Inputm">Nom</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inputm-7" placeholder="Nom" name="NOM" value="test">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input2m">Emplacement</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input2m-7" placeholder="Emplacement" name="EMPLACEMENT" value="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input3m">Utilité</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input3m-7" placeholder="Utilité" name="UTILITE" value="S">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input4m">Marque</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input4m-7" placeholder="Marque" name="MARQUE" value="HP">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input5m">Modèle</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input5m-7" placeholder="Modèle" name="MODELE" value="EWE">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input6m">Numéro de série</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input6m-7" placeholder="Numéro de série" name="NUMEROSERIE" value="DFERu">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input7m">Processeur</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input7m-7" placeholder="Processeur" name="PROCESSEUR" value="weWE">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input8m">Mémoire</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input8m-7" placeholder="Mémoire" name="MEMOIRE" value="wesdf">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input9m">OS</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input9m-7" placeholder="OS" name="OS" value="ESFDdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input10m">Catégorie</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input10m-7" placeholder="Catégorie" name="CATEGORIE" value="Cdeqawed">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input11m">Valeur</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input11m-7" placeholder="Valeur" name="VALEUR" value="989">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="Soumettre" value="Soumettre" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>





    <form name = form2 action="/delete" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="20" value="Delete" class="btn btn-outline-danger" />
    </form>



    <!--20-->
    <!--<form action="/update" method="put">
      <input type="submit" name="20" value="Update" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
    </form>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-outline-danger" />
    </form>-->
  </td>
  <!--20-->
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>21</td>
  <td>r5y</td>
  <td>5ry</td>
  <td>r5y</td>
  <td>y5r</td>
  <td>w3</td>
  <td>ww3</td>
  <td>w3</td>
  <td>55</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>677</td>
  <td>
      <div class="container">

          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Modifier</button>

          <!-- Modal -->

          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modifier serveur</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form name="form1m" action="/update" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Inputm">ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inputm5-8" placeholder="ID" name="ID" value="21" readonly>
                      </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Inputm">Nom</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inputm-8" placeholder="Nom" name="NOM" value="r5y">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input2m">Emplacement</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input2m-8" placeholder="Emplacement" name="EMPLACEMENT" value="5ry">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input3m">Utilité</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input3m-8" placeholder="Utilité" name="UTILITE" value="r5y">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input4m">Marque</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input4m-8" placeholder="Marque" name="MARQUE" value="y5r">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input5m">Modèle</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input5m-8" placeholder="Modèle" name="MODELE" value="w3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input6m">Numéro de série</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input6m-8" placeholder="Numéro de série" name="NUMEROSERIE" value="ww3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input7m">Processeur</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input7m-8" placeholder="Processeur" name="PROCESSEUR" value="w3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input8m">Mémoire</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input8m-8" placeholder="Mémoire" name="MEMOIRE" value="55">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input9m">OS</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input9m-8" placeholder="OS" name="OS" value="6">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input10m">Catégorie</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input10m-8" placeholder="Catégorie" name="CATEGORIE" value="7">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Input11m">Valeur</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input11m-8" placeholder="Valeur" name="VALEUR" value="677">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="Soumettre" value="Soumettre" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hm, my first bet would be, that the `id`s must be unique.
Have you tried to replace `id="Input2m"` with `id="Input2m-<%=i%>"`? (That is, adding the loop index to it).

Comment: Okay, can you help me?
Is your problem, that the rows in the same table contain all the same data (like in row 1)? If so, could you show, how `data` looks like?
Or is your problem, that the table shows different data, but the form submission processes only the first row? (If so, could you show the rendered HTML?)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, i modified these :

```
id="myModal1"
data-target="#myModal1"
```

to this :

```
data-target="#myModal1-<%=i%>"
id="myModal1-<%=i%>"
```

Comment: Great!
Don't forget to update the `for` attributes as well! This way, clicking on a `<label>`  will focus the associated `<input>`.